# Word 365 banded rows out of sync when one row is deleted

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table with blue & white banded rows. I delete a row. Now I have two blue rows next to each other. I try to turn off banded rows in Table Tools > Design and then turn them on again, but that doesn't fix the problem. I still have two blue rows next to each other.

How am I supposed to get back to alternating colours?

Comment: insert a new row, transfer the data, then delete the incorrect cell.

Comment: Annoying to have to do this but it works. Many thanks.

Comment: If it is a standard style, or the style is saved, just apply it on the table again. Still annoying if you have a lot of tables, but less so.

Answer (score 0):

It is a defect in the way a table appears when you have track changes turned on. Simply select the table and accept the changes. The strange banding disappears. :-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).